# Play/Scala injecting controller into test

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, scalatest, playframework-2.4

So according to Play 2.4 documentation (https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Unit-Testing-Controllers), the controller should be set up as a trait like this

```
trait ExampleController {
  this: Controller =>

  def index() = Action {
    Ok("ok")
  }
}

object ExampleController extends Controller with ExampleController
```

in order for a test to work like this

```
class ExampleControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Results {

  class TestController() extends Controller with ExampleController

  "Example Page#index" should {
    "should be valid" in {
        //test code
    }
  }
}
```

however, I'm using Guice dependency injection, and according to Play 2.4 documentation (https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection) my controller looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class ExampleController @Inject() (exampleService: IExampleService) extends Controller {
    def index() = Action {
        Ok("")
    }
}
```

Since controller is no longer a trait and I can't mix it into the test like this: `with ExampleController`, how do I make the test above work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit directly from ExampleController.  You can also eliminate the `extends Controller`, as your controller already inherits this:

```
class TestController(service: IExampleService) extends ExampleController(service)
```

You can find more information about testing using Play and Guice [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, any idea how to inject the service (that is injected into the controller) into the same test as well?

Comment: I'd mock out the service, eg: using ScalaMock.

Comment: I don't understand, what would be the benefit of creating a class TestController and testing it, instead of testing the ExampleController directy?